# jquery keep hover state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an hidden element which contains a list. What I want to achieve is, to keep the hover state while moving from the clicked div with the cursor to the element with the list. The element which contains the list, should first disappear as soon as I go away from it e.g point away with the cursor. How can I achieve that?

I have this markup:

```js
$('.hover').hover(function() {
  $('.hoverDiv').addClass('show')
}, function() {
  $('.hoverDiv').removeClass('show')
})
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hoverDiv {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.hoverDiv.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="hover">
    <p>
      hover this div
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="hoverDiv">
    show me when hovered
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xpfk6xe5/1/)

Comment: It's better to change html a little bit: https://jsfiddle.net/xehpjjoy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind the hover event to the `.container` instead of the `.hover` div. because when the user will move out from `.hover`, the list will be hide. But when user move on the `.hoverDiv` he still on the `.container`

```js
$('.container').hover(function() {
  $('.hoverDiv').addClass('show')
}, function() {
  $('.hoverDiv').removeClass('show')
})
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hoverDiv {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.hoverDiv.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="hover">
    <p>
      hover this div
    </p>
    <div class="hoverDiv">
      show me when hovered
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By the way, should don't need a script for this. You can do this using css only. Like this:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hoverDiv {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container:hover .hoverDiv {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="hover">
    <p>
      hover this div
    </p>
    <div class="hoverDiv">
      show me when hovered
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @artemisian alright I'll accept this answer then :-) Both answers are great though

Answer (score 2):

Try this jquery code:

```
$('.hover').hover(function(){
    $('.hoverDiv').addClass('show')
})
$('.hoverDiv').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.hoverDiv').removeClass('show')
});
```

```js
$('.hover').hover(function(){
  $('.hoverDiv').addClass('show')
})
$('.hoverDiv').mouseleave(function(){
  $('.hoverDiv').removeClass('show')
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hoverDiv {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.hoverDiv.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="hover">
    <p>
    hover this div
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="hoverDiv">
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
      <li>Four</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Steve it will not work if the `.hoverDiv` will be far from the `.hover` div (let's say `margin` or something)

Comment: @Steve, Mosh Feu  is right, his CSS solution is the best solution of all proposed for a specific set of requirements. It all depends on your requirements.

Comment: @artemisian You are very kind :)

Comment: Np @Mosh Feu, IMHO the purpose is to solve the problem in the best possible way. Steve, one draw back of my approach is that the user will have to trigger a mouseleave on the list in order to close it, which I personally don't like.